# SSD and HDD at same time in Dell XPS L502X

Tags: dell-xps

I have Dell XPS 15 L502x laptop with 750GB HDD. I want to know that can I install additional SSD in this laptop to decrease boot time and app load time.

I checked internet and found that XPS 17 have additional slot for extra HDD.  here is the link

http://www.storagereview.com/dell_xps_17_ssd_upgrade_review

Can I install the SSD in Dell XPS L-502X

http://www.cnet.com/laptops/dell-xps-15-l502x/4505-3121_7-34539946.html

Comment: "can I install additional SSD in this laptop to increase boot time and app load time" - Wow, first time I've ever seen anyone request this!

Comment: Karan I am asking to install additional SSD and will install OS and apps on that SSD...

Comment: Yes, but why in the world would anyone want to ***increase*** the boot time and app load time instead of *decreasing* it?

Comment: @Karan just looking my previous questions. Sorry it was my mistake that i wrote "increase" instead of "decrease". Apologize for that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can add a second drive to this laptop, and that second drive can be a SSD. In order to make room for that you need to remove the optical drive.

This gives you two options:

1. With no need for the optical drive.

   - Shutdown the laptop and remove power (both netpower and battery)
   - Flip the laptop over and remove the bottom cover (3 screws)
   - Remove the screw keeping the CDROM in place.
   - Replace that with the caddy with the SSD
   - And replace the screws and the covers. Plug in power.
     When you boot to the BIOS you should see two drives. The old HDD and the new SSD.
     After this I suggest doing a nice clean install on the SSD, update the OS and make a backup. The last in case you ever need to fix the OS after a virus infection, otherwise not related to installing the SSD).

     You can also move the old installation from the HDD to the SSD using Acronis. ghost or similar programs. I will not go into detail because there are already a lot of answers on this site on how to do that.
2. Or, if you need an optical drive and can't live without it:
   Open up the laptop, remove the old HDD and install the SSD in its place.
   If the SSD is too small for your taste then putting the old HDD in an external case (e.g. via eSATA or USB) will help, but seriously consider if two drives and no CDROM or an external CDROM isn't a better option. (Hint: you can rip the movies to disk, which means you will never need an optical drive again).

[This recording on youtube](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=__c80xeQlgk) shows removing the optical drive and replacing it with a caddy. It might be worth watching.

Answer (score 1):

The only way you are going to increase your boot time and application response time is by moving your entire Operating System onto the SSD. The SSD is what has the faster read and write speeds but if it's all located on the HDD then you are going to see no difference at all. That's why it is best to install the OS onto the SSD and your programs as well and store all of your extra data onto the other drive that you have.

Comment: How would the SSD increase boot and application response time?

Comment: Karan read this. I think you are not aware the difference between HDD and SSD  http://www.storagereview.com/ssd_vs_hdd

Comment: @Mohsan: I think it is *you* who are confused. An SSD is faster than an HDD, so it will decrease response time, not increase it.

Comment: It was an obvious typo/thinko.  Still fun to read though. :)

Comment: @Karan I apologize. It was typo mistake. Sorry

Answer (score 0):

As JustinD points out, you would have to image your OS partition to the SSD to notice any performance.  But what you are describing is also the very intent of Hybrid Drives.  [A Hydrid Dive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hybrid_drive) uses both spinning disk and flash memory techology to acheive fast boot times and while keeping the cost lower for the same amount of storage that of a purely SSD.  The flash memory essentially acts as a huge cache (something like 32 GB) where most of your OS and programs get stored for fast loading.

Comment: But my question is that Can I install additional SSD in Dell XPS 15 L502X ???