# Installing SSD in IDE vs ODD Dell XPS L502x

Tags: ssd, dell-xps

I have Dell XPS L502x and planning to install 240GB SSD.

There could be two options

1--> Replace the internal 750GB HDD with 240GB SSD and install HDD in Optical Disk Drive via Caddy.
2--> Keep the internal HDD as its location and install the SSD in Optical Disk Drive via Caddy.

which could be the best option considering performance of SSD.

AFAIK Internal HDD operates over SATA interface where as ODD (Optical Disk Drive) operates over IDE. First one is much faster than IDE.

What do you suggest?

I want to keep OS and installed programs on SSD.

**Finally I installed Samsung 830 at Native SATA III Port by replacing existing HDD**

Comment: You can't connect a SATA drive to IDE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found your old thread on this from 3 years ago.

[SSD and HDD at same time in Dell XPS L502X](https://superuser.com/questions/518840/ssd-and-hdd-at-same-time-in-dell-xps-l502x)

The link you posted in the original question explains that your main hard drive slot is SATA3 6gb/s, while your optical bay and eSata port is SATA2 3gb/s. Therefore, depending on the ssd drive you buy, if you put it into the optical bay, you may not be able to reap the benefits of its maximum speeds. Did you over look the information that you posted or are you just unfamiliar with sata speeds...?

FYI:
http://www.samsung.com/global/business/semiconductor/minisite/SSD/global/html/whitepaper/whitepaper02.html

Answer (score 0):

You have to check to which bus your CDROM is connected, and then make your decision. For example in my macbook i see both CD and HDD on SATA3 bus. in general, for high speed bus wires length counts, so better put new SSD in HDD bay, and HDD move to caddy.